# solve this differential equation using laplace transform and the series method :

Tags: power-series, laplace-transform

Problem : $y''+8ty'-16y = 3 , y(0) = y'(0) = 0 $

I am supposed to use the series method to get F(s) , then get the inverse laplace transform to get f(t).

I got the Laplace transform : $(s^3 - 24s) F(s)   - 8s^2F'(s) = 3 $

then I started using the series method and ended up with $\sum\limits_{n=3}^\infty [C_{n-3} -16C_{n-1} - 8n C_{n-1} ]s^n = 3 $

and I am not sure if that's right since the coefficient of $x^{0}$ is clearly not 0 .

Comment: I think there is an issue with your LT.

Comment: that's a simplified version of it ( I brought the s from the RHS to the LHS).  I did the LT multiple times so i think it's ok.

Comment: Perhaps you should look at the LT of $8 t y'$ again.

Comment: yes I see what you mean. I will fix it and see. Thanks

Comment: I fixed it now, but the problem is still there: I dont know why the 3 is there while the coefficient of $x^0$ is 0 .

Answer (score 0):

Integrating by parts twice we have:
\begin{equation}
\int\limits_0^\infty y^{''}(t) e^{-s t} dt = -y^{'}(0) - s y(0) + s^2 F(s)
\end{equation}
Likewise:
\begin{equation}
\int\limits_0^\infty y^{'}(t) e^{-s t} dt = -y(0) + s F(s)
\end{equation}
finally:
\begin{equation}
\int\limits_0^\infty t y^{'}(t) e^{-s t} dt = \left. y(t) t e^{-s t} \right|_0^\infty  - \int\limits_0^\infty y(t) \left( 1 e^{-s t} + t (-s) e^{-s t}\right) dt = - F(s) - s F^{'}(s)
\end{equation}
Bringing all terms together we get:
\begin{equation}
\left(s^2 - 24 \right) F(s) - 8 s F^{'}(s) = \frac{3}{s}
\end{equation}

Now, we make the usual ansatz $F(s) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n s^{n+r} $. Inserting this into the equation we get:

\begin{equation}
\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \left(a_{n-2} - a_n (24 + 8 (n+r))\right) s^{n+r} = 0
\end{equation}
and
$-24 a_0 s^r - 8 a_0 r s^r = 3/s$ and $-24 a_1 s^{r+1} - 8 a_1 (r+1) s^{r+1}= 0$. Thus $r=-1$, $a_0 = -3/16$, $a_1=0$ and $a_{n-2} = a_n (16 +8 n)$. This leads to the following solution:

\begin{equation}
F(s) = \frac{3\left(1 -  e^{\frac{s^2}{16}} \right)}{s^3}
\end{equation}

However, instead of assuming the power series expansion we could just assume $F(s) = A s^r$. Inserting this into the equation for the Laplace transform leads to another solution:

\begin{equation}
F(s) = \frac{3}{s^3}
\end{equation}

which is readily inverted  and gives

\begin{equation}
f(t) = \frac{3 t^2}{2}
\end{equation}

By inserting the last equation into the original ODE we verify that this is the correct solution.

Comment: you forgot to get the LT of the RHS.

Comment: yes I know, sorry ;-)

Comment: But how can you get the inverse LT of $e^{s^2 / 16} $ ?

Comment: $\frac{3s^2}{2}$ is actually the answer, but how can we get it by the series method ?

Comment: Is it a stupid question or a hard one?